# Display PHP results in HTML page

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to construct an HTML page where I want to have a button and when I click on it, some php code executes on the server "selecting" from a postgre database and displays the results back to the HTML page. The php code is in a different file from the HTML and works fine. Can anyone help?

Comment: Good question! So you don't know google.....right?

Comment: post your code.what you want?

Comment: AJAX is the way to go. Check out jQuery.ajax (google)

Comment: What you're describing is usually implemented using AJAX. Use that to find more information on what it is and how to use it.

Answer (score 2):

Use jQuery in my opinion. It's extremely easy:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

$('.getDataButton').click(function(){
    $.post( "php/phpdata.php",{data : data}, function( data ) {
      $( ".result" ).html( data );
    });
});
```

The function(data) part contains any returned php values.

Answer (score 0):

I think AJAX is the keyword you should google for. Optional with JQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You can use AJAX for requesting the PHP script on the server. Use jQuery if you are familiar with it.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not familiar with either of these. Any other way?

Answer (score 0):

AJAX is the way.

If you haven´t started on your webpage yet, you can check out for example JSP(if you are familar with java).. or eventually .NET ASP.NET from Microsoft. Both these frameworks make it very easy to accsess databases inside your application.

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this in your HTML age...

```
<form action="welcome.php" method="post">
```

Comment: I did this but it's redirecting me to the php file where I can't format the results.

Comment: u can add your code there. And you can show your results there.

Comment: `<form action="results.php" method="post">`: Direct the submission to the page that will display the results. It's as simple as changing the existing `.html` suffix to `.php` and then inserting code to format the results. (Though if you can figure out ajax, you can insert the results into the current page instead of loading a new one).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use AJAX to process PHP without page reload.

jQuery-AJAX: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

On button click you can send parameters to that php-file via ajax. In your php-file you can handle this parameters with $_REQUESTS['param'] and then return your html to display it with jQuery.

Just append your return to some element.